# Проблема с подключением к вебсокету KuCoin`а

Tags: python, requests, websocket, https

Всем здравствуйте, пишу код на Python, пытаюсь использовать вебсокет криптобиржы KuCoin чтобы получать сообщения об изменениях моего баланса.

В [документации](https://docs.kucoin.com/#apply-connect-token) написано что нужно использовать один из 2-х токенов(публичный или приватный) для создания подключения к вебсокету. Публичный токен для публичных каналов и приватный токен для приватных каналов. Для того чтобы получить токен нужно отправить POST запрос на /api/v1/bullet-**public** или /api/v1/bullet-**private**. Ранее я уже использовал публичный канал для получения изменений в книге ордеров, вот код:

```
# Делаем POST Запрос и получаем токен
token = json.loads(requests.post('https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/bullet-public').text)['data']['token']

# Используем полученный токен для подключения к вебсокету
url = f'wss://ws-api-spot.kucoin.com?token={token}&[connectId={int(time.time())}]'
ws = create_connection(url)

# Подписываемся на изменения книги ордеров
request = {
    "id": int(time.time()),
    "type": "subscribe",
    "topic": "/spotMarket/level2Depth5:DOT-USDT",
    "privateChannel": False,
    "response": True
}
ws.send(json.dumps(request))

# Обрабатываем приходящие сообщения
while True:
    message = json.loads(ws.recv())
    ...
```

В случае с публичным каналом вопросов не возникало. Но для того чтобы получать сообщения об изменениях моего баланса нужно использовать приватный токен, а для этого нужно авторизовываться. В [документации](https://docs.kucoin.com/#authentication) написано что каждый приватный запрос должен иметь следующие заголовки:

- **KC-API-KEY** The API key as a string
- **KC-API-SIGN** The base64-encoded signature (see Signing a Message)
- **KC-API-TIMESTAMP** A timestamp for your request
- **KC-API-PASSPHRASE** The passphrase you specified when creating the API key
- **KC-API-KEY-VERSION** You can check the version of API key on the page of API Management

Так же, там написано:

1. For the header of KC-API-SIGN:

Use API-Secret to encrypt the prehash string {timestamp+method+endpoint+body} with sha256 HMAC. The request body is a JSON string and need to be the same with the parameters passed by the API.
After that, use base64-encode to encrypt the result in step 1 again.

2. For the KC-API-PASSPHRASE of the header:

For API key-V2.0, please Specify KC-API-KEY-VERSION as 2 --> Encrypt passphrase with HMAC-sha256 via API-Secret --> Encode contents by base64 before you pass the request."

Собственно вот мой код, который я написал для получения приватного токена следуя документации:

```
import json
import requests
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
from config import APIs

api_public = APIs['KuCoin']['public']
api_private = APIs['KuCoin']['private']
api_passphrase = APIs['KuCoin']['passphrase']


def make_signature(timestamp):
    string = timestamp + 'POST' + '/api/v1/account/balance'
    signature = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_private.encode('utf-8'), string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())

    return signature


def make_passphrase():
    passphrase = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_private.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
    return passphrase


def get_token():
    timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
    token = json.loads(requests.request(method='POST', url='https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/bullet-private', headers={
        'KC-API-KEY': api_public,
        'KC-API-SIGN': make_signature(timestamp),
        'KC-API-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'KC-API-PASSPHRASE': make_passphrase(),
        'KC-API-KEY-VERSION': '2'  # Это версия моих API ключей, которые я создавал на сайте
    }).text)
    print(token)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_token()
```

Данный код должен был бы сделать print токена получего для приватного канала, но я получаю не токен а вот такое сообщение `{'code': '400005', 'msg': 'Invalid KC-API-SIGN'}`

Прошу помощи у тех кто сталкивался с такой же или с похожей проблемой

Comment: Вы создаете подпись вашего запроса, указывая для *endpoint* значение `/api/v1/account/balance`, а запрос отправляете на `/api/v1/bullet-private`, вот и получается ошибка подписи

Comment: Да, действительно. Спасибо вам

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том что при создании подписи я использовал /api/v1/account/balance вместо /api/v1/bullet-private. Первую ссылку стоит использовать уже после подключения к вебсокету, сначала подключаешься а затем(используя первую ссылку) подписываешься на обновления